# Browsersync: Refused to execute script from 'XX/app.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, etc

Tags: javascript, gulp, mime, browser-sync

The issue only pops up when using Browsersync thus far, the script is called with `<script src='js/app.js' type="text/javascript"></script>`

I call Browsersync with:
`var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();`

```
browserSync.init({
        server: './dist',
    });
```

and the script being called is empty with a simple bit of code with a basic function that logs a string to the console.

I'm currently searching Browsersync options but finding nothing so far. Any advice?